# How to map the results of tests executed in Matrix mode to a Test Suite/Test plan in DevOps

Tags: c#, azure-devops, automated-tests, browserstack, vstest

I have set up a Test plan in DevOps which will get updated with testrun status after build deployment. It works fine when my "strategy" is parallel in the yml file(i.e. there is a 1-1 mapping for testcases run and the testcase in Testplan) but when my strategy is "matrix" then the same set of testcases will be executed in 2 different configurations(see the yml file sample), in this case after the testcases are executed how can i track the testrun for each configuration in DevOps testplan(since each testcases is executed twice)? are there any steps that i need to add under any of the tasks in yml file to specifically call out which test plan is updated by each of the items under matrix

```
jobs:
- job: 'BrowserStack'
  timeoutInMinutes: 0
  strategy:
    maxParallel: 2
    matrix:
      EdgeWindows:
        remotePlatform: 'EdgeWindows'
      SafariMac:
       remotePlatform: 'SafariMac'
```

I would want to segregate the test run output from the above matrix in my testplan but my actual test plan gets overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

When a test script is triggered to run on BrowserStack, a session is initiated.
You can group your sessions on BrowserStack into different builds by including the 'build' capability in your test script. You can configure the 'build' name, 'project' name and 'name'(name of a particular test) as per your use case.

For instance -

You can include the below capabilities in your test scripts-

'project' : 'project_name',
'build' : 'Build_Android',
'name' : 'test_name'